# Strange deformation on arm - Rigging

Tags: rigging

Whenever I try to move the arm forwards or backwards this deformation occurs. I've already tried weight painting but the problem still remains. What could it be? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Does the mesh or rig have non unit (1, 1, 1) scale?

Comment: I'm not sure If I get what you mean. You can take a look at the file :

https://pasteall.org/blend/6aa7698cd9754fc5a3dec3b037fa0ac4